# Configuring Org-mode to open PDFs with evince

Tags: emacs, pdf, file-opening, org-mode

I'm starting to use `org-mode` to export text to LaTeX.

My problem is that it opens the generated PDF with `ebook-viewer` (it is a EPUB, CHM reader) instead of using evince.

*Question*

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour and configure `evince` to be the default viewer?

Comment: As noted in a comment below, if the accepted answer doesn't work, see [Properly setting default external PDF reader in emacs org-mode - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/644447/properly-setting-default-external-pdf-reader-in-emacs-org-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewer should be the same as that chosen when you use `xdg-open` or simply double click a pdf in a file manager. The default file associations are set in either `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` (global) or one of `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` or `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`.

For example, this is what I have on my system:

```
$ grep -i pdf /usr/share/applications/defaults.list 
application/pdf=evince.desktop;atril.desktop
```

Assuming you have the corresponding `.desktop` file in the right location (`/usr/share/applications/` for example), `emacs` should just find it and open with the right viewer.

Comment: This didn't work for me. For anyone having the same problem: This did: https://superuser.com/questions/644447/properly-setting-default-external-pdf-reader-in-emacs-org-mode

Comment: Neither this solution nor the one in the above comment worked for me.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and Emacs 27.1; not sure if this resulted from some poor configuration of my system, but I solved this problem by updating `org-file-apps-gnu` to using `default` instead of `mailcap` -- it seems that an ebook viewer had a higher priority than evince for opening pdfs.  You could also check the settings in the mailcap file, see `man update-mime`.

Comment: @RJTK that sounds like it deserves to be its own answer. It's going to be hard to spot buried in the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested to turn my comment into an answer.

The accepted solution, nor the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/644447/properly-setting-default-external-pdf-reader-in-emacs-org-mode) solved the issue for me.  I had the problem using `org-ref` (for managing bibtex entries), so it might be particular to the function `org-ref-open-bibtex-pdf` which subsequently calls `org-open-link-from-string` ->`org-link-open` and `org-open-file`.

I'm not sure why, but it was eventually going over to a constant `org-file-apps-gnu` to check which program to use, and the default setting was to refer to mailcap.  I overrode this in my config, replacing `mailcap` with `default`, which would match with `org-file-apps`.  I believe this caused it to then defer to the priority set up in `xdg-open` as described in the accepted solution.

An alternative solution in this case would have been to modify the `mailcap` settings, which can be done by modifying the global `/etc/mailcap.order` or the local `~/.mailcap.order` (which may not exist).  More details can be found by consulting `man update-mime`.